# Does RekeyLimit property in sshd_config enforce Re-keying/Key re-exchange?

Tags: ssh

I have set the **RekeyLimit** property in **sshd_config** and tried to perform a ssh. But I could not see rekeying happening in the verbose logs, all I see is the below log message at the start of the session (in my sshd server logs).

> debug3: rekey after 2048 bytes, 0 seconds [preauth]

Only when I enable the **RekeyLimit** on my ssh client (**ssh_config**)/ use ~R, do I see the logs pertaining to the rekeying activity.

Is this expected?
Shouldn't the **RekeyLimit** property in **sshd_config** enforce rekeying?

I am using OpenSSH 6.7.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check:

rekeying is part of the SSH2 protocol only, so you'd need to make sure you were making SSH2 connections in all cases.

Did you signal/restart the server when changing the config?  Usually you can kill -HUP on a server to restart it and cause it to re-read the config file.